# FB App not showing updates

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've made an app using the Custom Story Graph tool provided by Facebook, and I got it working most of the way. I've managed to be able to send post requests to post using a users ID (well, I'm using 'me' in this case, but shouldn't matter, right?). And although I can see it clear as day in my Activity Log, it wont appear on my personal page.

*Yes, I have changed it from "Allow on timeline" to "Show on timeline"*.

But still nothing appears. My only guess is it might have something to do with the parameters I pass to it upon post, but they're all valid.

Before I started adding coordinates to the map, it did appear. But obviously without any coordinates.

This is how I post at the moment: [image: Posting to News Feed]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. As far as I can tell, the issue occurred because I was posting data which did not completely satisfy the requirements for GeoPoints for Maps. Although I got no error when these details were missing, it worked after I fixed them.

If anyone should ever need:
Geopoints consists of
'double Altitude'
'double Latitude'
'double Longitude'